# как параметр mysql передать в виде переменной

Tags: bash, sh

Например есть такой запрос

```
SQL="$(mysql --init-command='SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' -D database -N -e 'show databases')"
```

Как сделать `str="--init-command='SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'"`, чтобы передавать в строку запроса что-то типа такого:

```
SQL="$(mysql "$str" -D database -N -e 'show databases')"
```

И чтобы если параметра нет запрос отрабатывал без него

Дополнение:
(Запрос show databases для примера)
Сейчас смотрю в сторону составления строки и потом выполнения с помощью eval

Comment: Чем плохо `SQL="$(mysql -D database -N -e 'SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;show databases')"`? К слову, `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` ну никак не может влиять на `show databases`...

Comment: @Akina это хорошо, но вопрос звучал как параметр mysql передать в виде переменной, и запрос подставлен как "например".

Comment: @PotroNik Эммм... боюсь, я не понял Вашей мысли. Просто у меня помещение в командную строку дополнительного `--init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;"`, литералом или через переменную среды, приводит именно к тому, что нужно автору - но у меня Windows...

Comment: @Akina, как я понял, что запрос который указал автор приведен лишь для примера, т.е. он тут играет второстепенную роль, что бы на его основании показать как можно решить задачу. И что тут ему не литерал нужен, а адаптация скрипта к работе с переменной и без. Ну это как я понял, возможно автору следует дополнить вопрос, что бы не было недопонимания подобного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписанный скрипт от @PotroNik:

```
#!/bin/bash

INIT_CMD=${1:-"SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0"}
QUERY=${2:-"show databases"}

mysql --init-command="$INIT_CMD" -D database -N -e "$QUERY"
```

Запускается так: `./mysql.sh "set names cp1251" "select * from mails"`

Answer (score 0):

Ответ стал общим:

Для удобства дальнейшего пользования, можно описать функцию:

```
mySQL () {
param1=${1:-"SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0"}
param2=${2:-"show databases"}
mysql --init-command="$param1"; -D database -N -e "$param2"
}
```

автор: [Total Pusher](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/287469/total-pusher)

После этого вызывает функцию с указанием параметра или без него, при простом вызове функции сработает условие по умолчанию.

```
mysql '--init-command=SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' -D database -N -e 'show databases'
```

передавать параметры для запуска:

```
mySQL "параметр1" "параметр2"
```

В случае необходимости указать только второй параметр, оставить пустые кавычки параметра1

Так же функции можно описать в отдельном файле, а после подгружать их в скрипт или терминал. К примеру добавим функцию в файл `/work/need/myfunc.sh`, теперь что бы в терминале появилась описанная функция выполняем команду `. /work/need/myfunc.sh`, аналогично функцию загрузить этой командой можно и в скрипте:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /work/need/myfunc.sh
res=`mySQL "" "select * from table"`
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что это bash, и его возможности ограничены, но этот скрипт слишком запутан. Можно переписать на подстановку параметров в `mysql $additionalParam ... -e "$query"`. А в том стиле, что сейчас - два параметра, а число `if .. elif` четыре. Это плохо читается. Для трех параметров будет 8, и так далее. Минусовал не я.

Comment: @TotalPusher я описал лишь возможность, можно все упростить или усложнить для своих потребностей, уверен будут еще варианты. Написать функцию, пусть даже не указанную в примере потратить 15 минут, а потом пользоваться вызывая набор команд одним словом. Полезные для себя функции сразу в .bashrc прописал, мне удобно. Но это не значит что я говорю что это единственное решение.

Comment: подумайте о следующих поколениях, которые будут копипастить и добавлять "свою лапшу" в такое решение. Переписал ваш же скрипт в более простой, чтобы показать, что я имел в виду.

Comment: @TotalPusher и у вас отлично получилось и донести до меня информацию что вы имели ввиду.